# Angular 11 - 'Cannot match any routes' using children routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I have a multi-module Angular 11 project and I am trying to implement routing.

Based on the documentation, I did this:

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'articles',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/articles/articles.module').then(m => m.ArticlesModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`articles-routing.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleComponent } from './components/article/article.component';
import { ArticlesComponent } from './components/articles/articles.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: ArticlesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':articleId',
        component: ArticleComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ArticlesRoutingModule { }
```

`ArticlesComponent` works as expected at `localhost:4200/articles`, but when I try to open `localhost:4200/articles/48451` to load `ArticleComponent` I get the following error:

`Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'articles/48451' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'articles/48451'`

Comment: Can you please post `.html` files in order to see the usage of `router-outlet` tag?

Comment: I only have one router-outlet in the app-component.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the `ArticleComponent` in a `<router-outlet>` inside the `ArticlesComponent`, you need to remove the `pathMatch:"full"` otherwise it won't be able to match any children.

If both routes/components are independent, add two Routes instead of nesting them in children.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: ArticlesComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':articleId',
    component: ArticleComponent
  }
];
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

@Chaka15 is right in the meaning that you should have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your articles.component.html file.

In your routes configuration, you state that: ArticleComponent is a child of ArticlesComponent. In technical terms, it means that: when you access the route "localhost:4200/articles/48451", the router engine will first process the ArticlesComponent and then look for "`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`" inside the articles.component.html

Here's the docs for that part https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#child-route-configuration